# Can a Video Game be More than Just Entertainment?

Tags: ethics, life, philosophy-of-technology

I'm interested in creating video games that influence people in a positive way.  On the surface, this seems like a tech question, but in reality, it's more philosophical.  For instance..

1. Why do games cause many to disengage from the real world?
2. Why do social games encourage behavior we wouldn't attempt in the "real" world (e.g.: immoral or risky acts)?
3. What are the key differences between the real world and virtual
   world that are relevant to these behavioral differences?  After all, both can have a real effect (e.g.: my acts can hurt the feelings of real people in a social game)
4. What makes things fun?
5. What makes things seem like work?
6. How can 4 & 5 be reconciled?

How can we leverage our understanding of the above to develop games that encourage the development of morals, success, achievement and problem solving while remaining fun?

Comment: This isn't a philosophical question.  However, a quick answer to your question is "yes".  Look up edutainment.  I've used games to teach and learn, and one genre of games that has helped me a lot are typing games, which got my typing speed up to 120 wpm!  Not bad for a guy who failed typing in high school :D

Comment: Also, I wouldn't let your passion for productive games be your guide. If you get into the industry, chances are you'll need to work on whatever they tell you to work on, so you're likely to spend your time on non-productive games.  For you to realize your vision, you might have to pursue it independently, as a labor of love.

Comment: in the most alien way i love you man, thank you for the inspiration. Also i have no idea where else i could post this quest, i figured it had to do with morality, or something along those lines so i posted here. A quick question to the wise, should i remove this question or leave it be to see what happens??

Comment: My pleasure.  Edutainment is a passion of mine (I'm a software developer, but I don't work in the games industry).  Go ahead and leave the question up.  I may be wrong and perhaps this is a good fit for this site.  If you can, try editing the question to make its philosophical connections more obvious.  This should help against closing.

Comment: yeah i would not know to put this in philosophical terms, i am a philosophy noob, couldn't you edit it? or give me some ideas.

Comment: not worth an answer, but: every game including the need of cooperation between players are a playground for learning and applying moral concepts. Even more if they include factions. WoW is a place where you can get an idea of which people are highly immoral in quite a short time, for example.

Comment: The http://www.lumosity.com/ people earnestly hope so, and the people at https://www.superbetter.com/ seem to have proof.  On a more theoretical level, the more artistic end of game design is as edifying as literature, and perhaps as engaging as drama.  Tim Robbin's approach to anti-recidivism in prisons relies entirely upon literature and drama as tools, and is one of the most effective programs for ending criminal recycling.  So there is a lot of territory with great promise.

Comment: @ChrisAscencio I'll edit it to try to give it more philosophical relevance.  Another thing you can look at is gamification.

Comment: @ChrisAscencio ok, I edited it and added some more tags.  It's more obviously philosophical, I hope it still preserves the spirit of your question.

Comment: On 1) there's the critique of Spectacle by Debord, and of the culture industry by the Frankfurt school that might have a bearing on this; also Arendts observation on the rise of the *social* as opposed to *civic* society; on 2) Hobbes and Rousseau come to mind.

Comment: As edited this is now a psychology question, still not a philosophical one.

Comment: I could imagine an adventure game or an RPG in which the player's character is presented with moral choices that have consequences for the other characters. This would have to be handled very skilfully: it would be pointless just to have something like "you stabbed this person, so your reputation goes down 5 points". Like a good novelist, you would need to provide enough story and depth that the player cares about the characters in the game and doesn't want them to be hurt, or maybe does want some of them to be hurt if they deserve it.

Comment: @bumble: I heard on the radio a few months ago about a group which were researching how to use virtual reality to do something similar - presenting the world through the eyes of an other - ie different gender, ethnicity etc.

Comment: @Bumble interesting idea.  Encouraging behavior by providing a pay-off only encourages self-interested (not moral) behavior.  Maybe morality is tied with being able to see the other as a person, which in itself requires us to put them in the context of a story?  It also puts an interesting spin on methods people use to dehumanize each other (basically, altering their stories or suggesting they have none).  This also ties in nicely with "narrative theories of self".

Comment: These are a series of four episodes on games in education by the folks at  [Extra Credits](http://extra-credits.net), those guys tackle the questions you've asked on a regular basis in their show.
#[An End to Fear](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWyPLNi8rD8), 
#[Responsive Learning - How Games Help Teachers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzmdx7ZL8OM),
#[How Games Prepare You for Life - 21st Century Skills](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hoeAmqwvyY)
#[How Games Empower Us - Agency](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T39kYzzv_3Q).